# if a function returns true then return a tree with all nodes for which the function returns true

Tags: ocaml

Can anybody tell me why my function doesn't work when is about "f v" i get this error "This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type tree"

```
let rec function1 t f=
  match t with
  | Nil -> Nil
  | T (l, v, r) ->
    if f l v r then T (function1 l f, f v, function1 r f) 
    else T (l, v, r)

let f x = x mod 2 = 0;;
type tree = Nil | T of tree * int * tree;;
```

the tree is needed to be in preorder traversal

Comment: The calls `f l v r` in your condition and `f v` in the reconstructed tree don't match and/or don't make sense. What do you want to pass in the function to test against, and what do you want the returned tree to look like?

Comment: I want my tree to contain just the nodes for which the function f=x mod 2=0 returns true

Comment: Yes, given that function has only one parameter you shouldn't pass three arguments. Also you want to return the same nodes, not a tree of booleans as values.

Comment: What happens if a node returns false? Do you neglect its left and right branches or do you continue with its left and right branches?

Answer (score 0):

`f l v r` makes the compiler think that `f` is a function taking 3 arguments. What I think you want is `f v`

Also, if you want this tree to only contain nodes with even values, this branch should be something like this:

`|T(l,v,r)->if f v then T( function1 l f, v,  function1 r f) else Nil`

This keeps the node with even value `v` and recurses on its left and right subtrees, but if the value is odd, it cuts off the node and its children.